# “fatal: index file corrupt” keeps repeating in git

Tags: git

The following error keeps repeating even after I’ve tried the recommended:

```
rm .git/index
git reset
```

But I still get this error:

```
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
fatal: 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule '[directory path omitted]'
```

What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: go to the backups?

Comment: it's just the index file at fault right? i don't really want to go back and examine previous commit and manually merge many differences..

Comment: The recommendations I see say `rm .git/index` - note the dot. *However*, you may want to read all the comments at [“Index file corrupt”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1115956/1115360).

Comment: n.b. Original version before someone kindly formatted it included the .git ... is there a particular comment in that link that I'm missing?

Answer (score 8):

I had that problem, and I tried to fix it with this:

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

BUT it did not work. **The solution**?
For some reason I had other .git folders in sub directories. I delete those .git folders (not the principal) and `git reset` again. Once they were deleted, everything worked again.