# 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule

Tags: git

Whenever I try to commit I get these errors:

```
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
fatal: 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule amazon-s3-php-class
```

Why? What's wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/837668/fatal-index-file-corrupt-keeps-repeating-in-git

Comment: It's not a duplicate exactly since it adds an additional line in the error message. This is about what `git status --porcelain' failed` entails

Comment: Look in the other question. Directory path omitted.

Comment: Please remove the amazon-web-services tag, this is a git question.